# Is the energy of the Ising model random or deterministic?

Tags: energy, statistical-mechanics, temperature, ising-model

I'm reading about the Ising model and I'm confused by the following point. It says that the probability of finding the model in a given state $s$ is proportional to $e^{-E(s)/T}$. Where $E(s)$ is the energy of the state and $T$ is the temperature.
On the one hand, if the state is random, then, since the energy is a function of the state, so is the energy. But on the other hand isn't the energy also determined by the non-random temperature $T$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, at finite temperature the energy is a random variable  with PDF
$$p_T(E) = \rho(E)\, e^{-E/T}$$
where the density of states $\rho(E)$ depends on the details of the Hamiltonian. When people talk about "the energy of the thermal state at temperature $T$", they really mean the average energy
$$\langle E \rangle_T := \int_0^\infty E\, p_T(E)\, dE.$$
But the energy is indeed a random variable, so there will be fluctuations, and an instantaneous measurement of the energy could measure a value other $\langle E \rangle$ (although for a large system, the relative deviation away from $\langle E \rangle$ will almost always be very small).

Comment: So is the temperature random too then?

Comment: @SebastianOberhoff No, in the canonical ensemble formalism, the temperature is a non-fluctuating constant - just a constant parameter in the Boltzmann weight $p(s) \propto e^{-E(s)/T}$. The energy is a random variable whose PDF depends on constant parameter $T$. The *average* energy $\langle E \rangle_T$ is a fixed function of the parameter $T$.

Comment: Forgive my naivety, but I thought energy was a function of temperature? Are there other random components that also go into the energy of the Ising model and allow it to be random, even though the temperature is not?

Comment: @SebastianOberhoff  Temperature  is an intensive thermodynamic variable of bulk matter, characterizes the bulk. Even in classical statistical mechanics  it is the average kinetic  energy distribution that is connected to temperature. see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/temper.html

Comment: @SebastianOberhoff The energy is not a *deterministic* function of temperature. It is a random random variable whose *PDF* is a deterministic function of temperature. The randomness comes from our ignorance of the instantaneous microstate of the heat bath to which the system is coupled, which determines the system's instantaneous energy. But the whole point of statistical mechanics is that we don't need the heat bath to appear as an explicit random variable in any of our equations - all thermodynamic quantities depend only on its single constant parameter $T$.

Comment: @tparker So if I'm understanding you correctly, $T$ is not the temperature of my idealized magnet, it's the temperature of the magnet's environment?

Comment: @SebastianOberhoff Well, in thermal equilibrium the magnet and the environment are at the same temperature. I would phrase it as saying that environment's temperature determines the magnet's temperature, since it's so much bigger that its energy fluctuations are negligible. But yes, it's fair to say that the temperature is more directly a property of the environment than of the magnet.

Answer (score 1):

The expression

$$p(s) = e^{-E(s)/k_B T}$$

is valid in the [canonical ensemble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_ensemble), where the fixed macroscopic variables are particle number $N$, volume $V$ and temperature $T$. This means that the energy can fluctuate: it is "random". This is valid for *any* system in the canonical ensemble, not just for the Ising model.

The magnitude of the fluctuation of energy $\sqrt{\langle E^2\rangle - \langle E \rangle ^2}$ can be calculated in general and it has the value

$$\sqrt{\langle E^2\rangle - \langle E \rangle ^2} =T \sqrt{k_B C_V}$$

This means that the relative fluctuation is

$$\frac{\sqrt{\langle E^2\rangle - \langle E \rangle ^2}}{\langle E \rangle} =\frac{T \sqrt{k_B C_V}}{\langle E \rangle} \propto \frac 1 {\sqrt N}$$

where we have used $C_V \propto N$ and $\langle E \rangle \propto N$ (heat capacity and energy are *intensive variables*). This means that for a macroscopic system, where $N\approx10^{24}$, the energy fluctuations will become vanishingly small, and *fixing the temperature becomes equivalent to fixing the energy*.

In other words, $E$ is a random variable in the canonical ensemble (fixed $NVT$), but its probability density has a very sharp peak centered at $\langle E \rangle$.

Comment: I think you mean that heat capacity and energy are extensive variables.